# crear csv despues de scrapear una web

Tags: python-3.x, csv, scraping

me estoy iniciando en Scrapear webs, concretamente lo quiero scrapear son web de estadísticas de futbol para crear mi propia base de datos. Principalmente elijo esto porque quiero aprender a scrapear y me gusta el futbol, hehehehe

Bueno, a continuación os dejo mi código.

De momento sólo me descargo una web y busco 5 o 6 resultados sencillos con la idea de practicar cómo crear un .csv y el problema que encuentro la forma de crear dicho archivo.

A ver si algún alma caritativa de este maravilloso foro me ayuda con esta ardua tarea y me dice cómo terminar de crear mi .csv

Muchas gracias a todos

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
url = 'https://es.besoccer.com/partido/salernitana-calcio-1919/lecce/202353462/analisis'
besoccer = requests.get(url)
s = BeautifulSoup(besoccer.text, 'lxml')
type(s)
print(s.prettify())
import numpy as np
def obtener_stats(s):
    stats_dict = {}
    
    competition = s.find('h3', attrs={'class':'competition'})
    if competition:
        stats_dict['competition'] = competition.get_text('/', strip=True)
    else:
        stats_dict['competition'] = None
        
    homeTeam = s.find('p', attrs={'itemprop':'homeTeam'})
    if homeTeam:
        stats_dict['homeTeam'] = homeTeam.get_text('/', strip=True)
    else:
        stats_dict['homeTeam'] = None
    
    homeRank = s.find('div', attrs={'class':'position t1'})
    if homeRank:
        stats_dict['homeRank'] = homeRank.get_text()
    else:
        stats_dict['homeRank'] = None    
    
    homeGoals = s.find('div', attrs={'class':'content-box t-1'}).find('div', attrs={'class':'poss-box'})
    if homeGoals:
        stats_dict['homeGoals'] = homeGoals.get_text('/', strip=True)
    else:
        stats_dict['homeGoals'] = None     
    
    awayTeam = s.find('p', attrs={'itemprop':'awayTeam'})
    if awayTeam:
        stats_dict['awayTeam'] = awayTeam.get_text('/', strip=True)
    else:
        stats_dict['awayTeam'] = None     
        
    awayRank = s.find('div', attrs={'class':'position t2'})
    if awayRank:
        stats_dict['awayRank'] = awayRank.get_text()
    else:
        stats_dict['awayRank'] = None     
        
    awayGoals = s.find('div', attrs={'class':'content-box t-2'}).find('div', attrs={'class':'poss-box'})
    if awayGoals:
        stats_dict['awayGoals'] = awayGoals.get_text('/', strip=True)
    else:
        stats_dict['awayGoals'] = None     
 
    draw = s.find('div', attrs={'class':'content-box draw'}).find('div', attrs={'class':'cont'})
    if draw:
        stats_dict['draw'] = draw.get_text('/', strip=True)
    else:
        stats_dict['draw'] = None    
    
    return stats_dict

obtener_stats(s)

df = pd.DataFrame()
df.head()
```

Comment: En que estás trabado? En que te podemos ayudar para que termines el código?

Comment: Pues el problema es que no crea el archivo .csv

Comment: creo que me falta definir algo en el DataFrame, pero realmente no doy con la tecla

Comment: Crear el dataframe no crea el csv, tenés que usar df.tocsv

Comment: pufffff, vaya fallo de novato, yo se lo decía al código pero se me que no me escuchaba, hehehehehe

Comment: por favor, donde puedo encontrar documentación de cómo utilizarlo? gracias

Comment: Claro! https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html Pero recuerda investigar antes de preguntar, quizá hasta te ahorras preguntar.

Comment: correcto, no volverá a pasar, muchas gracias

Comment: cierra la pregunta

Comment: perdón, cómo se cierra?